# Javascript after pressing button make button colored where id and class =

Tags: javascript

I tried to search for this online but couldn't find anything that works

i want that after i press  then class where id = 1 is changed to cls-checked

```
<a id='1' class='cls-up' onclick='vote("up",this);'></a>
<a id='1' class='cls-down' onclick='vote("up",this);'></a>
```

after pressing vote it goes to php and like is pressed i want to make users already see like without reloading

```
function vote(vote, val)
        {
            var params = {"vote": vote, "id": val.id};
            $.ajax({
                data:  params,
                url:   'vote.php',
                type:  'post',
                success:  function (response) {

                }
            });
        }
```

problem is i always have 2 elements with same id if each element had different id i could use this code

```
var x = document.getElementById("1");
x.className = "cls-2";
```

Comment: How `vote`  is implemented ?

Comment: "_i always have 2 elements with same id_" Why? IDs within a document are supposed to be unique.

Comment: it's because these are like buttons and with id = image id so dislike and like button have same image that's why they are both same

Comment: But they can't share the same ID, that's invalid HTML, and messes your script ...

Comment: it's only html, and it's working it was the easiest way to solve the problem without writting any extra code

Comment: ?? It doesn't solve the problem, it creates more problems ...

Comment: i just need code which changes cls-up class to cls-checked where class = cls-up and id = 1

Answer (score 0):

On click check the id and then add class to existing classList

```js
function vote(e, status, elem) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (elem.id === '1') {
    elem.classList.add('cls-2')
  }
}
```

```css
.cls-2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a id='1' class='cls' onclick='vote(event,"up",this);'>Hello</a>
```

Comment: hmm i don't think this will work i have just edited my question

Comment: id has to be unique.there cannot be duplicate id

Comment: hmm yeah but it was only way i could make it work, and classes are different there just need code which finds class = cls-up with id 1

Comment: no its wrong way to do. Use tag selector with wildcard class name